# Convergence of multiplication operators

Tags: operator-theory

Problem: Let $B$ be a Banach space of functions on $X$ and $M_g$ for $g \in B$ denote the multiplication operator on $B$ defined by $M_g f (x) = g(x) f(x)$ for all $x \in X$.
Now consider a sequence $(g_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $B$ s.t. $g_n \rightarrow g \in B$.
What are general conditions guaranteeing $\|M_{g_n} - M_{g}\| \rightarrow 0$?

By brute force we can say that if $g_n \rightarrow g$ uniformly s.t. $\sup_{x \in X} (g_n(x) - g(x)) \rightarrow 0$, then there exists $N$ s.t. $\|(g_n - g)f\| \leq \epsilon \|f\|$ for all $n \geq N$ and, hence, $\|M_{g_n} - M_{g}\| \rightarrow 0$.

Any other ideas or specific references?

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Comment: This question does not seem clear to me. If $g\in B$, and $B$ as an unspecified Banach space, what is $g(x)$? When you write $g_n\rightarrow g$, what kind of convergence are you thinking of? What is $X$?

Comment: I was too sloppy here. I was thinking of a function space, see my edits. In particular, I'm after conditions for norm convergence of the multiplication operator. Obviously, poin twise convergence is insufficient.